# Custom Android app not launched during Android Management API enrollment with the setupActions keyword

Tags: android-management-api

Following the Android Management API reference, we've configured our Android Companion App to be automatically launched during the enrollment.

We've added the following information in our `policy` configuration:

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/XXX/policies/85f57716-8b02-48f2-abdf-5aeb6beef585",
  "version": "1",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "app.XXX.companionapp.test",
      "installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "managedConfiguration": {
        "namespace": "XXX",
        "enterpriseId": "enterprises/XXX"
      }
    }
  ],
  "openNetworkConfiguration": {
    "NetworkConfigurations": [
      {
        "Type": "WiFi",
        "GUID": "a0989e28-9c23-43e5-b5d3-9b37d86723a3",
        "WiFi": {
          "AutoConnect": false,
          "Passphrase": "XXX",
          "Security": "WPA-PSK",
          "SSID": "SFR-9548"
        },
        "Name": "XXX"
      }
    ]
  },
  "systemUpdate": {
    "type": "AUTOMATIC"
  },
  "safeBootDisabled": true,
  "statusReportingSettings": {
    "applicationReportsEnabled": true,
    "deviceSettingsEnabled": true,
    "softwareInfoEnabled": true,
    "memoryInfoEnabled": true,
    "networkInfoEnabled": true,
    "displayInfoEnabled": true,
    "powerManagementEventsEnabled": true,
    "hardwareStatusEnabled": true
  },
  "stayOnPluggedModes": [
    "BATTERY_PLUGGED_MODE_UNSPECIFIED"
  ],
  "locationMode": "HIGH_ACCURACY",
  "appAutoUpdatePolicy": "ALWAYS",
  "playStoreMode": "WHITELIST",
  "setupActions": [
    {
      "launchApp": {
        "packageName": "app.XXX.companionapp.test"
      },
      "title": {
        "defaultMessage": "Companion"
      },
      "description": {
        "defaultMessage": "Install Companion App to run custom tasks on your device."
      }
    }
  ],
  "passwordPolicies": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

It used to work well, but lately, our companion app is not launched anymore during enrollment, whereas it's actually installed on the device.

Do you have any idea about what could be wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: There is a mismatch in the `SetupAction` key. In the Android Management API guides, it refers to `setupAction`, and in the API documentation it refers to `setupActions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue on Google's side preventing the new `setupActions` feature to work. This issue is now fixed and the feature is now working properly.

Comment: Hi @Fred, I've installed ```Youtube``` and set it to ```Launch``` during setup and it's working fine. 
But when will the work setup complete? Because I opened the app and went back to the Setup but it still shows to ```START``` the app and below it ```Your Work phone is ready```

Comment: As explained in [the guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#launch_an_app_during_setup) the app must return RESULT_OK to signal completion and allow Android Device Policy to complete device or work profile provisioning. Therefore this likely won't work with an app that you don't own since you can't make changes in that app.

Comment: @Fred Hi Fred,
What exactly is meant by app returning `RESULT_OK`. How do I make  my app return it after the launch?

Comment: You can set the result with [`Activity.setResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) and then call `Activity.finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

The wifi configured here is for later use or use at the first step after scan the QR Code. I configured the wifi in the policy but after scan the QR code it always asks to connect to wifi.

Comment: Hi Florian, @Fred can you help to confirm?